# Regular Expression Lookahead Alternative

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
30.03.2014
```

And I need a regular expression, which gives me this part:

```
03
```

I am not allowed to use lookahead, because it is not supported.
The expression should just return the string between the ".".
The expression I made:

```
\.(.*?)\.
```

Grabs the string between the dots, including the dots:

```
.03.
```

I don't want the dots to be in the result. This is where I tested it: [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/38vn6)

Thanks.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: My answer should be "don't use regular expressions to parse" and point you towards any kind of Date library/object in the language you are using, so I better don't post it. ;) Also, when using RegExr, hover over the result and check what it lists as "group", because that's what your `()` group wraps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can replace `(.*?)` with `(\d+)`

Next thing is that your regex works correctly, you just need to get matched group (for example in PHP it will be `$matches[1]`). What you see in your demo is whole string that is matched with regex (ie. `$matches[0]`), not only the `[1]` group you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is correct. All you have to do now is use your favourite programming language to grab what's between the brackets. For each programming language, there's a different syntax for this.